# times method returns nil with hash

Tags: ruby, random, hashmap

What I did is get random 2 values from hash and match them with the keys. My code gets two random values, that part works well. But when it comes to p hash[m], I expected it would print the key of hash, instead it returns nil. For example :

Our random values are "cat" and "ocean". The program pick this values by itself with times method.

So when m = "cat" hash[m] should be "dog", but it's nil. The same thing goes for "ocean" too. So I have two nil values. Why? How can I fix that and get the right key?

```
hash = { "foo" => "bar", "cat" => "dog", "ear" => "nose", "ocean" => "sea"}
value = hash.values

2.times do 
  m = value[rand(value.size)]
  p hash[m] #Erroneous part
end
```

Comment: If you want to search by value, use `p hash.invert[m]` otherwise if you want to find by key, change `value = hash.values` to `value = hash.keys`

Comment: For `p hash[m]` to work, `m` needs to be a key, not a value. Also, typically, you access the hash using keys, not values, so change the code to select by key (then you get the value easily as `hash[my_key]`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the key/value pairs at random by selecting the **keys** at random, since that's easier:

```
my_hash = { "foo" => "bar", "cat" => "dog", "ear" => "nose", "ocean" => "sea"}
my_keys = my_hash.keys

2.times do
  rand_key = my_keys[rand(my_keys.size)]
  rand_val = my_hash[rand_key]
  puts "#{rand_key} => #{rand_val}"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that you are given a hash and wish to select two values at random and then identify the keys associated with those values. For example, if

```
hash = { :a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3 }
```

the values are

```
values = hash.values
  #=> [1, 2, 3]
```

In this example the values are unique. Later I will address the general case where the values are not unique (e.g., `{ :a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3, :d=>2 }`).

If two values are to be selected randomly we would write

```
random_values = values.sample(2)
  #=> [2, 1]
```

In statistical terms, [Array#sample](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-sample) samples [without replacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_random_sample) (see paragraph 3). By contrast,

```
random_values = 2.times.map { values[rand(values.size)] }
```

samples two values *with replacement*, so `random_values` might equal, for example, `[2, 2]`.

Once `random_values` is obtained (assume `[2, 1]`) there are two ways to obtain the associated keys:

The first is as follows.

```
associated_keys = random_values.map { |v| hash.key(v) }
  #=> [:b, :a]
```

though it might be more useful to construct a hash that associates keys with the random values:

```
random_values.each_with_object({}) { |v,h| h[v] = hash.key(v) }
  #=> {2=>:b, 1=>:a}
```

See [Hash#key](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-key). The second way is to use [Hash#invert](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-invert):

```
hsaH = hash.invert
  #=> { 1=>:a, 2=>:b, 3=>:c }
```

Then we simply compute:

```
hsaH.values_at(*random_values)
  #=> [:b, :a]
```

or

```
hsaH.slice(*random_values)
  #=> {2=>:b, 1=>:a}
```

See [Hash#values_at](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-values_at) and [Hash#slice](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-slice).

---

Now consider the general case where the values are not unique. Suppose

```
hash = { :a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3, :d=>2 }
```

where keys `:b` and `:d` have the same value.

```
values = hash.values
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 2]
```

Then if we write

```
random_value = values.sample(2)
```

we could obtain `random_values #=> [2, 2]`. That may be permitted, but if two *unique* values are needed we would write

```
unique_values = values.uniq
  #=> [1, 2, 3]
random_values = unique_values.sample(2)
  #=> [3, 2]
```

The choice of whether to use `values` or `unique_values` depends on the application. Regardless, if the result is `[3,2]`, using the first approach above we obtain

```
keys = hash.keys
  #=> [:a, :b, :c, :d]
associated_keys = random_values.map { |v| hash.key(v) }
  #=> [:c, :b]
```

This may be unsatisfactory, however, as it depends on the ordering of the `hash`'s keys. Suppose:

```
hash = { :a=>1, :d=>2, :c=>3, :b=>2 }
```

In this case we get a different answer:

```
keys = hash.keys
  #=> [:a, :d, :c, :b]
associated_keys = random_values.map { |v| hash.key(v) }
  #=> [:c, :d]
```

Simlarly,

```
{ :a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3, :d=>2 }.invert
  #=> {1=>:a, 2=>:d, 3=>:c} 
{ :a=>1, :d=>2, :c=>3, :b=>2 }.invert
  #=> {1=>:a, 2=>:b, 3=>:c}
```

the values of `2` being different.

For the general case (again, depending on the application), we might consider writing the following.

```
hash = { :a=>1, :d=>2, :c=>3, :b=>2 }
values_to_keys = hash.each_with_object({}) do |(k,v),h|
  (h[v] ||= []) << k
end
  #=> {1=>[:a], 2=>[:d, :b], 3=>[:c]}
```

Then

```
values = hash.values
random_values = values.sample(2)
  #=> [3, 1] 
random_values.map { |v| [v, values_to_keys[v].shift] }
  #=> [[3, :c], [1, :a]]
```

A second example:

```
random_values = values.sample(2)
  #=> [2, 2] 
random_values.map { |v| [v, values_to_keys[v].shift] }
  #=> [[2, :d], [2, :b]]
```

Note that in the calculation of `values_to_keys`, `(h[v] ||= []) << k` expands to

```
(h[v] = h[v] || []) << k
```

so if `h` does not have a key `v`, this becomes

```
(h[v] = nil || []) << k
(h[v] = []) << k
```

causing `h[v]` to be set equal to an empty array, which is returned, followed by `k` being appended to that empty array. By contrast, if `h` already has a key `v`,

```
(h[v] = h[v] || []) << k
  #=> (h[v] = h[v]) << k
  #=> h[v] << k
```